# HowTo assign a UIViewController to a UITabbarControllers Tab programmatically

Tags: storyboard, segue, swift3, xcode8

I have two different kinds of profile for users. One is for general member and one is for premium members. I created the app using `Storyboard` in `Xcode 8`. After the app launches it asks the user whether he is a general member or premium member. For general member the flow works fine with segues linked in `Storyboard`. A `UITabbar` with profile icon takes the user to the profile. But how can I load the premium members profile in the same `Storyboard` programmatically ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? "HowTo replace a `UIViewController` within a `UITabbarController`?" Or "HowTo instantiate a `UIViewController` from Storyboard programatically"? Or both?

Comment: I want conditional check on the profile. Whether a user has pressed the button on 'premium member' then on tab bar button pressed will take him to premiumm members profile . But I linked all the viewcontrollers in storyboard by CTRL dragging. How can I do this programmatically

Answer (score 0):

A `UITabbarController` has an `Array` property, that holds the `UIViewController`s represented by its tabs. I have no time to test, but in principle you can get it via:

```
let tabBarController = self.view.window.rootViewController
let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers
```

Then you can modify it to your needs, for instance set premium login to first tab:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let premiumVc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifierOfPremiumVC_mustBeSetInStoryboardsInspector") as! UIViewController
viewControllers[0] = premiumVc
```